# Stripe API Authentication Error: 'You did not provide an API key"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment, mern

I'm integrating the Stripe payment gateway into my MERN project and I'm encountering an authentication error when trying to make API requests to Stripe. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
StripeAuthenticationError: You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.
```

Here's the relevant part of the error stack trace:

```
D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Online Movie Ticket Booking System\server\node_modules\stripe\cjs\RequestSender.js:96
err = new Error_js_1.StripeAuthenticationError(jsonResponse.error);
^
```

I've double-checked my code and environment variables to ensure that I'm correctly setting and using my Stripe API keys and also getting the stripeApikey in App.jsx, I console log there. However, I'm still encountering this authentication error.

Here's how I'm using the Stripe API key in my code:
PaymentController:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

router.post("/process", async (req, res, next) => {
  const myPayment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: req.body.amount,
    currency: "inr",
    metadata: {
      company: "Mahadi",
    },
  });

  console.log("Stripe Secret Key:", process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    client_secret: myPayment.client_secret,
  });
});

router.get("/stripeapikey", async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Stripe API Key:", process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY);

  res.status(200).json({ stripeApikey: process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY });
});

module.exports = router;
```

App.jsx:

```
const [stripeApikey, setStripeApiKey] = useState("");

  async function getStripeApikey() {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${server}/payment/stripeapikey`);
      setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApikey);
      console.log("Stripe API Key:", data.stripeApikey);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching Stripe API key:", error);
    }
  }
  console.log(stripeApikey);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStripeApikey();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        {stripeApikey && (
          <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApikey)}>
            <Routes>
              <Route
                path="/booking"
                element={
                  <ProtectedRoute>
                    <BookingPage />
                  </ProtectedRoute>
                }
              />
            </Routes>
          </Elements>
        )}
```

BookingPage.jsx:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };

      const paymentData = {
        amount: ticketPrice * 100, // Stripe requires amount in cents
      };

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `${server}/payment/process`,
        paymentData,
        config
      );

      const client_secret = data.client_secret;

      if (!stripe || !elements) {
        toast.error("Stripe or Elements not initialized.");
        return;
      }

      const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
        },
      });

      if (result.error) {
        toast.error(result.error.message);
      } else {
        if (result.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
          const reservationData = {
            movieName,
            theaterName,
            showDate,
            selectedShowtime,
            selectedHall,
            selectedSeats,
            ticketPrice,
            paymentInfo: {
              id: result.paymentIntent.id,
              status: result.paymentIntent.status,
              type: "Credit Card",
            },
          };

          dispatch(createReservation(reservationData));
          toast.success("Reservation successful!");

          navigate("/ticket", {
            state: {
              movieName,
              theaterName,
              showDate,
              selectedShowtime,
              selectedHall,
              selectedSeats,
              ticketPrice,
            },
          });
        } else {
          toast.error("Payment processing failed. Please try again.");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
  };



         <div className="w-[50%] mb-5">
              <label className="block pb-3 text-[black]">
                Exp Date <span className="text-red-500">*</span>{" "}
              </label>
              <CardExpiryElement
                className="w-full border p-1 rounded-[5px]"
                options={{
                  style: {
                    base: {
                      fontSize: "15px",
                      lineHeight: 1.5,
                      color: "#444",
                    },
                    empty: {
                      color: "#3a120a",
                      backgroundColor: "transparent",
                      "::placeholder": {
                        color: "#444",
                      },
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="w-full pb-3 ">
            <div className="w-[50%] mb-5">
              <label className="block pb-3 text-[black]">
                Card Number <span className="text-red-500">*</span>{" "}
              </label>
              <CardNumberElement
                className={`w-full border p-1 rounded-[5px] !h-[35px]`}
                options={{
                  style: {
                    base: {
                      fontSize: "15px",
                      lineHeight: 1.5,
                      color: "#444",
                    },
                    empty: {
                      color: "#3a120a",
                      backgroundColor: "transparent",
                      "::placeholder": {
                        color: "#444",
                      },
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="w-[50%] ">
              <label className="block pb-3 text-[black]">
                CVV <span className="text-red-500">*</span>{" "}
              </label>
              <CardCvcElement
                className="w-full border p-1 rounded-[5px] !h-[35px]"
                options={{
                  style: {
                    base: {
                      fontSize: "15px",
                      lineHeight: 1.5,
                      color: "#444",
                    },
                    empty: {
                      color: "#3a120a",
                      backgroundColor: "transparent",
                      "::placeholder": {
                        color: "#444",
                      },
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: On `console.log("Stripe Secret Key:", process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)`, do you see the API key, https://stripe.com/docs/keys from your account? Instead of passing `(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)` can you try hard coding your API key there like `const stripe = require("stripe")('sk_test_123');`? Does it work?

Comment: Yes the hardcoding works